Icons/favicon for flutter web with flutter_launcher_icons based on flavor
I have been working on generating icons for flutter project.
I was able to achieve generating app icons for android and ios based on flavor with flutter_launcher_icons package. However, I am stuck at managing icons for web (which are icons and favicon) based on flavor.
here are the three files for each flavor.

flutter_launcher_icons-dev.yaml

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: "assets/launcher_icon/my_app_dev.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#ffffff" # You can use a color or image for the background
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/launcher_icon/my_app_dev.png" # For adaptive icons on Android
  adaptive_icon_foreground_inset: 16 # only available for Android 8.0 devices and above
  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/launcher_icon/my_app_dev.png"
    background_color: "#hexcode"
    theme_color: "#hexcode"


flutter_launcher_icons-staging.yaml

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: "assets/launcher_icon/my_app_staging.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#ffffff" # You can use a color or image for the background
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/launcher_icon/my_app_staging.png" # For adaptive icons on Android
  adaptive_icon_foreground_inset: 16 # only available for Android 8.0 devices and above
  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/launcher_icon/my_app_staging.png"
    background_color: "#hexcode"
    theme_color: "#hexcode"


flutter_launcher_icons-prod.yaml

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: "assets/launcher_icon/my_app_prod.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#ffffff" # You can use a color or image for the background
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/launcher_icon/my_app_prod.png" # For adaptive icons on Android
  adaptive_icon_foreground_inset: 16 # only available for Android 8.0 devices and above
  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/launcher_icon/my_app_prod.png"
    background_color: "#hexcode"
    theme_color: "#hexcode"

only differences between these three files are just the name of the flavor.(dev, staging, and prod).
And I run these to generate icons
[1] flutter clean

[2] flutter pub get

[3] dart run flutter_launcher_icons -f flutter_launcher_icons-<flavor_name>.yaml

My problem is this command does not generate folders based on flavor.
This is what it generates under web folder.

so they are the icons generated by the command with the flavor at the last time(I assume).
Okay. Personally, this is still okay as long as I can generate for prod environment. However I have follow-up problem where at [3] command above. when I run [3] command with prod flavor,
dart run flutter_launcher_icons -f flutter_launcher_icons-prod 

this triggers below at once. 
So I assume icons/favicon for prod and dev are overwritten by ones of staging(since I can only see one set of icons and favicon in first image above rather than in different named folders for each flavor).
so my ultimate question is either one of these two.

How to generate and manage folders for flutter web icons/favicon based on flavors(dev, staging, and prod)?
How to generate icons/favicon only for specific one flavor (rather than generating three at once)?

